# Program argument with space characters is broken by Eclipse when running the debugger

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, debugging

I have a program which needs seven arguments.
The problem is that the fifth argument has empty (space) characters.
So I put it in the double quotes and the program runs.

The problem:

When I try to use the debugger inside the Eclipse the system put \”  instead of “ . The result is the fifth argument is broken and I cannot use the debugger...

Here is what I have in the argument list

```
168815 blabla/ product_group_and_eshop_global_id blaee/test/test "<unique_string>products in the</unique_string><TotalNumberUniquestring>2</TotalNumberUniquestring><currentNumberUniquestring>1</currentNumberUniquestring><div_OR_table_navigatin_instructions><divORTableForward_skip>1</divORTableForward_skip> <divForward_in>1</divForward_in></div_OR_table_navigatin_instructions><type_of_product_substring>SEARCH</type_of_product_substring><where_to_search_the_name>title</where_to_search_the_name><currency>$</currency><price_extraction_start_Key>$</price_extraction_start_Key><price_extraction_end_Key>&lt</price_extraction_end_Key>" filename_mode
/src/cpp/test-pages/FrontLoad.html
```

And here's what the Eclipse print in the console

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `exec /media/Debug/gcom_au 168815 blabla/ product_group_and_eshop_global_id blaee/test/test \"<unique_string>products in the</unique_string><TotalNumberUniquestring>2</TotalNumberUniquestring><currentNumberUniquestring>1</currentNumberUniquestring><div_OR_table_navigatin_instructions><divORTableForward_skip>1</divORTableForward_skip> <divForward_in>1</divForward_in></div_OR_table_navigatin_instructions><type_of_product_substring>SEARCH</type_of_product_substring><where_to_search_the_name>title</where_to_search_the_name><currency>$</currency><price_extraction_start_Key>$</price_extraction_start_Key><price_extraction_end_Key>&lt</price_extraction_end_Key>\" filename_mode
/src/cpp/test-pages/FrontLoad.html'
```

Comment: This is probably an opportunity for you to reconsider the interface design of your program so that it becomes debuggable.  You should probably have an option to take the XML-ish argument with spaces from a file instead of requiring it to be on the command line, at least for the purposes of debugging.  I don't have a solution to the Eclipse-running-the-debugger problem for you — I can only suggest a way to circumvent the problem in the first place.

Comment: Try escaping individual space characters like this: `\ ` , instead of using quotes.

Comment: I have hard coded the fifth argument, just for the debugging ....  If anybody has better solution I would appreciated it.   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :  I  change the  “ to   '
So. the

```
168815 blabla/ product_group_and_eshop_global_id blaee/test/test "<unique_string>products in the</unique_string><TotalNumberUniquestring>2</TotalNumberUniquestring><currentNumberUniquestring>1</currentNumberUniquestring><div_OR_table_navigatin_instructions><divORTableForward_skip>1</divORTableForward_skip> <divForward_in>1</divForward_in></div_OR_table_navigatin_instructions><type_of_product_substring>SEARCH</type_of_product_substring><where_to_search_the_name>title</where_to_search_the_name><currency>$</currency><price_extraction_start_Key>$</price_extraction_start_Key><price_extraction_end_Key>&lt</price_extraction_end_Key>" filename_mode /src/cpp/test-pages/FrontLoad.html
```

becomes

```
168815 blabla/ product_group_and_eshop_global_id blaee/test/test '<unique_string>products in the</unique_string><TotalNumberUniquestring>2</TotalNumberUniquestring><currentNumberUniquestring>1</currentNumberUniquestring><div_OR_table_navigatin_instructions><divORTableForward_skip>1</divORTableForward_skip> <divForward_in>1</divForward_in></div_OR_table_navigatin_instructions><type_of_product_substring>SEARCH</type_of_product_substring><where_to_search_the_name>title</where_to_search_the_name><currency>$</currency><price_extraction_start_Key>$</price_extraction_start_Key><price_extraction_end_Key>&lt</price_extraction_end_Key>' filename_mode /src/cpp/test-pages/FrontLoad.html
```